# Hoverable Dropdown menu Add-in Commands

Tags: office-js, office-ui-fabric

Is there a way to make an Dropdown menu Add-in Command hoverable?  Basically, when you hover your mouse over the button the list of menu items automatically expands.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the scenario you've described is currently supported. As described in the [Menu controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands#menu-controls) section of the **Create add-in commands** article in the docs, the submenu displays as a drop-down list *when the button is selected* (i.e., when the button is clicked/pressed).

Comment: You're probably right.  The only reference to the add-in command button is in the manifest.  It's nowhere to be found in the html.  I'm thinking there might be some hack.